Como obtener las dos primeras palabras de una cadena con el metodo split?
Buenas tengo el siguiente problema. Lo que quiero es dividir una cadena con el método split() en js, pero no lo he podido lograr.
Lo que quiero es obtener la primera y segunda palabra de una cadena de texto que esta divido por un guion, pero por la posición.
Este es un ejemplo que estaba viendo por las webs:
let saludo  = "La-ciudad - grande",

palabras = saludo.split(' - ')[0] // me imprime "La-ciudad"

console.log(palabras)

Y esta normalmente me devolvería esto: La-ciudad , parece ya resuelto , pero es solo un ejemplo .
Poniendo esto en practica en mi programa pues no me funciona y la única manera de obtener la primera y segunda palabra es por la posición de la palabra.
Lo que quiero es obtener las dos primeras palabras que estan divididas por un guion, pero por la posicion[]:
palabras = saludo.split(' - ')[0] // con esto me obtiene la primera palabra "La" , pero estoy intentando obtener la segunda palabra ala vez, pero no me sale.

palabras = saludo.split(' - ')[0][1] // algo así intento, obtener palabras pero por la posición.

Gracias a los ejemplos y respuestas de ustedes , hasta cierto punto me funciono, pero me surgió el siguiente inconveniente.
Presento lo que quiero hacer:
Tengo las siguientes variables title y artist , estas ocupan una posición , que son la 1 y la 2 , estas son leídas por una api. Como es el titulo es el [0] y el artista es la [1], todo bien hasta allí, el problema me surgió cuando hay artistas que llevan un guion en medio y pues en este caso, las posiciones [0] como [1] solo ocuparían el nombre del artist , mas no el title.
title = api.songtitle.split(" - ")[0];
artist = api.songtitle.split(" - ")[1];

Hice la prueba de colocar una posición mas extra que seria la [2]. Gracias a que me dieron esta idea y pues me funciono hasta cierto punto. Pues de echo funciona bien cuando es un artist con "-" ya que se ocupa las tres primeras posiciones [0][1][2], pero cuando es un artist sin "-" pues solo existe la posición [0]y[1], la [2] no existe.
Y pues me parece indefinido la variable title.
title = api.songtitle.split(" - ")[2]; //agregue // me aparece indefinido si no tiene "-" un guion.
artist = api.songtitle.split(" - ")[0] + '-' + api.songtitle.split(" - ")[1]; // aqui se concateno las posiciones.
Lo haría de esta forma en la variable artist .split(' - ', 2) , pero me aparece separado por una coma y eso no es lo que quiero exactamente.

Tu dices esto: saludo.split('-')[0] + saludo.split('-')[1]; ???

@Yussef siii mil gracias! <3

Podes pasar el límite como segundo parámetro. Mira la documentación.
Podes concatenar 2 strings con + o unir todos los elementos de un arreglo en un string podes usar join pasándole el separador como parámetro.


let saludo  = "La - ciudad - grande",

palabras = saludo.split(' - ', 2)

console.log(palabras.join(" "))



También podes usar la desestructuración para tomar las primeras 2 palabras del arreglo.


let saludo  = "La - ciudad - grande",

[p1, p2] = saludo.split(' - ')

console.log(p1 + " " + p2)



